# AS3 display Text from XML file on dynamic textfield

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to have my dynamic text field on my stage display the quantity data from my XML file.

My XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <data>
        <item>
            <quantity>4470</quantity>
            <avg_sentiment_score>3.4596106511524</avg_sentiment_score>
            <total_votes>1</total_votes></item>
    </data>
    <errors></errors>
</root>
```

My AS3 code :

```
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("summaries.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
function processXML(e:Event):void 
{
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXML.*);
    quantity_txt = xml.quantity.text()[0];
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try : `quantity_txt.text = myXML.data.item.quantity;` ...

Comment: Or `myXML..quantity`.